# "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided." for general views

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt, djoser

I have created a custom user model and apply Djoser authentication and jwt. But after this when I tried to get request for products views, I get this error:

> "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."

Here is the screenshot:

[image: of Postman]

Here is the product_views.py:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated, IsAdminUser
from rest_framework.response import Response
from base.serializers import ProductSerializer ,ProductCategorySerializer 
from base.models import Product, ProductCatogory, Review
from rest_framework import status


@api_view(['GET'])
def getProducts(request):
    query = request.query_params.get('keyword')
    if query is None:
        query = ''

    products = Product.objects.filter(
        name__icontains=query)
    serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAdminUser])
def createCategory(request):
    new_category =  ProductCatogory.objects.create()
    new_category.save()

    return Response('new category created successfully')


@api_view(['PUT'])
@permission_classes([IsAdminUser])
def editCategory(request, pk):
    data = request.data
    category = ProductCatogory.objects.get(id=pk)
    category.product_category = data['product_category']
    category.save()
    serializer = ProductCategorySerializer(category, many=False)

    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['DELETE'])
@permission_classes([IsAdminUser])
def deleteCategory(request, pk):
    product_Catogory = ProductCatogory.objects.get(id=pk)
    product_Catogory.delete()
    return Response('Category is deleted successfully')

@api_view(['GET'])
def getCategorys(request):
    product_category = ProductCatogory.objects.all()
    serializer = ProductCategorySerializer(product_category, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(['GET'])
def productsByCategory(request,pk):
    category = ProductCatogory.objects.get(id=pk)
    products = category.product_set.all()
    serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
@api_view(['PUT'])
def updateProductCategory(request,pk):
    data = request.data

    product_id = data['product_id']
    product = Product.objects.get(_id=product_id)
    category = ProductCatogory.objects.get(id=pk)
    product.category = category

    product.save()

    return Response('category added successfully')
  




@api_view(['GET'])
def getTopProducts(request):

    products = Product.objects.filter(
        rating__gte=4).order_by('-rating')[0:5]
    serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(['GET'])
def getProduct(request, pk):
    product = Product.objects.get(_id=pk)
    serializer = ProductSerializer(product, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAdminUser])
def createProduct(request):
    user = request.user

    product = Product.objects.create(
        user=user,
        name='Sample Name',
        price=0,
        brand='Sample Brand',
        countInStock=0,
        
        description=''
    )

    serializer = ProductSerializer(product, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(['DELETE'])
@permission_classes([IsAdminUser])
def deleteProduct(request, pk):
    product = Product.objects.get(_id=pk)
    product.delete()
    return Response('Product is deleted successfully')


@api_view(['PUT'])
@permission_classes([IsAdminUser])
def updateProduct(request, pk):
    data = request.data
    product = Product.objects.get(_id=pk)

    product.name = data['name']
    product.price = data['price']
    product.brand = data['brand']
    product.countInStock = data['countInStock']
    product.description = data['description']

    product.save()

    serializer = ProductSerializer(product, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(['POST'])
def uploadImage(request):
    data = request.data

    product_id = data['product_id']
    product = Product.objects.get(_id=product_id)

    product.image = request.FILES.get('image')
    product.save()

    return Response('Image was uploaded')


@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def createProductReview(request, pk):
    user = request.user
    product = Product.objects.get(_id=pk)
    data = request.data

    # 1 - Review already exists
    alreadyExists = product.review_set.filter(user=user).exists()
    if alreadyExists:
        content = {'detail': 'Product already reviewed'}
        return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    # 2 - No Rating or 0
    elif data['rating'] == 0:
        content = {'detail': 'Please select a rating'}
        return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    # 3 - Create review
    else:
        review = Review.objects.create(
            user=user,
            product=product,
            name=user.first_name,
            rating=data['rating'],
            comment=data['comment'],
        )

        reviews = product.review_set.all()
        product.numReviews = len(reviews)
# if review = product and product = category 
        total = 0
        for i in reviews:
            total += i.rating

        product.rating = total / len(reviews)
        product.save()

        return Response('Review Added')
```

why I showed it here because I wanna show that there is need to be authenticated to get products.

here is settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for backend project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

from datetime import timedelta
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-jyhhr)v0kyrb+^ifdlio=p3mo&l=$(^an7xb&fow--z^rxd7^r'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'djoser',
    'base.apps.BaseConfig',
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',

    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'backend.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'backend.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'SOMEEMAIL@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'FOOO'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True


DJOSER = {
    'LOGIN_FIELD': 'email',
    'USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'USERNAME_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
    'PASSWORD_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
    'SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SET_USERNAME_RETYPE': True,
    'SET_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'USERNAME_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'email/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'ACTIVATION_URL': 'activate/{uid}/{token}',
    'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'user_create': 'accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user': 'accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user_delete': 'djoser.serializers.UserDeleteSerializer',
    }
}
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
       'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ( 'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser','rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated', ),

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',

        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )

}


...

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=30),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,
    'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': False,

    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    # 'SIGNING_KEY': settings.SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
    'AUDIENCE': None,
    'ISSUER': None,
  
    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('JWT',),
    'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',
    'USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule',

    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',

    'JTI_CLAIM': 'jti',

    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
}
# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'


CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
MEDIA_ROOT = "static/images"

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static"
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.UserAccount'
```

I have searched but they say to change the REST_FRAMEWORK's AUTHENTICATION PERMISSIONS which I have done as you can see, but to no avail.

Comment: Did you add your token in the headers of your request?

Comment: no I thought it did not need any token ......

Comment: You have to add the tokens from client side

Comment: Did you want this API to be accessed without tokens? Meaning even unauthenticated users will have access? If not, then you need the token to authenticate the user. Otherwise how will the api know which user is trying to access

Comment: Yes I want to get unauthenticated users will have access . It solved my issue do you know how to do this ?

Comment: If you are running Django on Apache using mod_wsgi you have to add

WSGIPassAuthorization On

in your httpd.conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open up the API on non-authenticated users, you need to give it an empty list on `authentication_classes`:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, authentication_classes, permission_classes


@api_view(['GET'])
@authentication_classes([]) # Add this
@permission_classes([]) # Maybe add this too
def getProducts(request):
    query = request.query_params.get('keyword')
    if query is None:
        query = ''

    products = Product.objects.filter(
        name__icontains=query)
    serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: It worked man . Thank you very very much . God bless you . But do I need to do this  on every view

Comment: On every view that you want anyone to have access to (which has zero security). Note that you will not get any user in `request.user`

Comment: thanks for telling because it is causing another issue .Now please provide the solution to for this

Comment: `request.user` needs `authentication_classes`. You need to think about your design. No authentication means no user.

Answer (score 2):

This thread is 1 year old but I was facing the same problem and I cannot have unauthorized access to my backend.

The issue with the configuration/usage is here:

> `'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('JWT',),`

When using this configuration, the Authorization header must be set with "JWT" instead of "Bearer".

For example, change:

```
"Authorization: Bearer <JWT token>"
```

to:

```
"Authorization: JWT <JWT token>"
```

Another option is to modify the settings file to the following configuration and use the regular Bearer Authorization header:

```
'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
```

I recommend the last option, as it is the most standard one.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add tokens in your headers?. if you have added then the access token must have expired so you can get a new access token from the refresh token

Add token in headers like Bearer token.

Comment: It solved my issue . thanks but I want anyone to get access to Product view even unauthorized users too . Can you tell me how to do this?